# How to effectively share OpenGL texture between two different processes?

Tags: opengl, vulkan

These processes are not related together in a way that one would be a child process of the other one.

The starting point is the OpenGL texture that has been rendered to in the host process that has its own GL context.
The client process now takes this texture already rendered on the host and presents it in the client's created window.

**Solution A**

The bad solution that comes to my mind is to create a shared memory between host and client process and use it like this:

**In host**: create the **host's GL context** and within host's context a GL texture, render the data to this texture and then write the content of rendered texture to the shared memory.

**In client**: create the **client's GL context** and within client's context a GL texture, do the readback to this GL texture from shared memory. Create a (HWND - it is on windows) window on client's side and use that texture for presentation in that window.

This is working, but it seems really ineffective to me, as you need to copy data from GPU memory to shared memory and then from shared memory to GPU again. Is there a way that data could stay all the time just in GPU memory?

I had an idea that I could use something like this...

**Solution B**

*On host:*

- Create Vulkan memory handle and image.
- Create OpenGL context, texture and mem. object.
- Bind that VkImage and GL texture together using that vulkan's memory handle and GL mem. object. By providing the resulting handle from `getMemoryWin32HandleKHR` (Vk) to `glImportMemoryWin32HandleEXT` (GL)
- Copy the render result from pure GL texture to this hybrid Vk/GL texture.
- Store the handle of the VkImage to the shared memory with handle of used VkInstance, VkDevice and all necessary stuff to reuse it in other process...

*On client:*

- Read VkImage handle from shared memory.
- Create new GL Context and new GL texture. Bind that GL texture to the VkImage handle from shared memory (another hybrid texture).
- Present in the window using the content form the GL Texture (this extra Vk->GL *"bind"* is necessary as the output is using basically a GL texture bind ID).

In my opinion this should work (although maybe I described some steps wrong as instead of the VkImage handles it is enough to put in the shared memory just result of `getMemoryWin32HandleKHR`, etc.).

Here everything except the handle that is shared through SharedMemory object between the processes stays in its place in a GPU memory, but I really don't like, that I need to use Vulkan's interop creating the gpu memory that can by shared between GL and Vk API (whne GL should be enough) and the fact that I need two separated GL contexts.

What I would really like to do is this:

**Solution C**

*On host:*

- Create the GL context and render to a GL texture.
- Store a pointer/handle to this GL context and GL texture bind ID in the SharedMemory object (CPU/RAM/Disc/ wherever...)

*On client:*

- Get the handle/pointer to the host's GL context and GL texture ID from the SharedMemory.
- Use this host originated texture and context and present result in the window created within client's process.

So basically this would mean: ommit the Vulkan and **reuse the GL context and texture in a different process then the one where they were originally created** - is this approach (Solution C) even possible without some horrific restrictions? As I am not aware of the way how to use **One** GL context in **Two** different processes, or is there some way?

Comment: Although I don't know for sure, but I'm very inclined that a single context can be shared between processes (solution C) and interaction with it should be handled by the OS and the driver. On the other hand you'll need to carefully synchronize the actions between host and client, as they will run concurrently and can modify each other's current bindings to VBOs, framebuffers, textures, etc

Comment: See also [this](https://community.khronos.org/t/sharing-context-between-processes/59760/15)

Comment: Yes, I read that one in the past, but I was not sure what was the conclusion, as they seemed to end up discussing the the GL context sharing between the threads (which I am aware is possible, but not quite recomended) and not processes, which I believe is something different in this case, but I am not sure about it.

Comment: Also if I create brand new GL context on client, is there a way I can get access to the GL texture created on the Host (with its own GL context)?